# Compare groups with same number of occurances of items in each group

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to solve a problem of matching a group of values to another group of values. What I want to do is to ensure that if a value is in first group is matched with a value in the other group, then that pair is sort of marked and we dont use those values again in comparing the groups. So for example,

[image]

So there are 4 groups in total. A-B, B-A, C-D, and D-C.
In each group there are multiple items.

What I want to do is compare groups A-B and B-A (just the opposite direction) and see if the values match exactly once in both the groups. So ID1 in group A-B has value 1000 which matches with ID5 in group B-A, similarly for ID2 in A-B matches with ID4 in B-A.
So both groups match.

Now if we consider Group C-D and D-C there is a problem, they do not match because although the values 666 and 777 can be found in each groups, but we need to use a value in comparison only if that value has not been matched before. So in this case

- ID7 in C-D is matched with ID11 in D-C,
- ID8 in C-D is matched with ID10 in D-C,
- ID9 in C-D Should NOT Matched (ID11 is already matched earlier).

Putting it in other words, sequence of match does not matter but the occurance of values does matter in each group.

I am expecting output like this

[image]

I am trying to do it in Excel and Power Query, but have no idea how to do it. Index columns or grouping might be helpful but I am not sure how to go about this problem.

The data has around 10000 rows and probably 2000 groups. The number of lines in each group are not fixed can range anywhere between 1-8. And the reverse groups also sometimes do not exist.

Comment: Seems like you just have a countif that counts matches based on the value and substring of the group, right? Perhaps surround with an if so that it only lists when count > 1?

Comment: I dont think countif will work, can you please show how you are suggesting it to be done

Comment: Please provide sample of the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work.  Can be pasted into PQ with Home ... Advanced Editor...

Assumes 3 columns with headers **ID**, **Group**, **Value** in range **Table1**

Duplicates **Group** column then splits the duplicate **Group** into two separate columns

Group the data by the 3 items -- **Group.1**, **Group.2**, and **Value**; then adds an **Index**, thus creating a cumulative count of each Value for that Group combination

Merges entire table on itself, but with **Group.1** matching **Group.2**, and **Group.2** matching **Group.1**

Expands. Anything without a match is ... unmatched and returns a null

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(Source, "Group", "Groupx"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Duplicated Column", "Groupx", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"-"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Group.1", "Group.2"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {"Group.1", "Group.2","Value"}, {{"Count", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index",1,1), type table}}),
#"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Count", {"Group", "ID", "Index"}, {"Group", "ID", "Index"}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Count",{"Group.1", "Group.2", "Value", "Index"},#"Expanded Count",{"Group.2", "Group.1", "Value", "Index"},"Expanded Count",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Expanded Count", {"Index"}, {"Match"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Expanded Count",{"Group.1", "Group.2", "Index"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns",{{"ID", Order.Ascending}})
in #"Sorted Rows"
```